# Is it possible for two recursive sequences to have the same characteristic equations

Tags: recurrence-relations

If I have a sequence, $\{t_1, \,t_2, \,t_1+t_2,\, t_1+2t_2,\cdots\}$ I know that the formula for it is:

$T_1=t_1, T_2=t_2, T_{n+2}=T_{n+1}+T_n.$

If there are two sequences, $A_n, B_n$ such that $A_1=1, A_2=0, A_{n+1}+A_n =A_{n+2}, B_1=0, B_2=1, B_{n+2}=B_{n+1}+B_n$

Then $A_n=F_{n-1}$ and $ B_n=F_{n-1}$  with $F_n$ being the Fibonacci numbers and $F_1=1, F_2=1$.

So the sequence becomes $T_n =t_1 F_{n-2} +t_2F_{n-1}$

The characteristic equation, which comes from $T_{n+2}=T_{n+1}+T_{n}$ is $x^2-x-1=0$ which has the roots $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. This is the same characteristic equation as the Fibonacci sequence.

Is it possible for two different sequences to have the same characteristic equation?

Comment: What does $t_1,t_2,t_1+t_2,t_1+2t_2$ mean?

Comment: that is the sequence given

Comment: Well, it doesn't make any sense.  What does the notation mean?  What, say, does $t_2, t_1$ mean?

Comment: $t_1$ is the first term, $t_2$ second term, $t_1+t_2$ third term, etc.. i don't know which part I am not defining correctly?

Comment: To your broader question, of course two sequences can have the same characteristic equation.  They just need to have different initial conditions.

Comment: Oh, got it.  I didn't understand that the terms were sequential.  Did my comment on the characteristic equation answer your question?

Comment: A recurrence of the form $a_n=pa_{n-1}+qa_{n-2}$ is obviously completely determined by any two consecutive values. In fact it is determined by any pair of values. This means that if two sequences match in two places they are identical. The same recurrence can have different initial values and these will generate a different sequence.

Comment: @lulu yes, thank you. sorry for such a simple question but it makes sense now